# [rospy] simultaneous subscribe at a given frequency

Tags: ros, rospy, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have 2 publisher who provide me 2 topics in real time, but I would like to write a listener which will, every 2 seconds, store the last topic published from those 2 publishers. And also, I'm coding in python. Do you have any idea?

Thanks and regards

Cyprien

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48697/%5Brospy%5D-simultaneous-subscribe-at-a-given-frequency/) by [Cyprien](https://answers.ros.org/users/3199/cyprien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not possible to subscribe at a given frequency, you have to filter the incoming messages yourself:

If the topics have to be synchronized, use a [TimeSynchronizer](http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters#Example_.28Python.29-1) for your subscription.
In your callback, check the last time you stored the messages and if it is more than 2 seconds ago, store again and store the timestamp.

If your topics do not have to be synchronized and you just want the output to be logged to a textfile you can use [throttle](http://ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/throttle) to republish your topic at the desired rate and [rostopic](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_echo) for logging:

```
rosrun topic_tools throttle messages /topic 2.0
rostopic echo -p /topic_throttled > topiclog.txt
```

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2